# ¿Error de sintaxis en el objeto?

Tags: javascript

estoy usando quokka para verificar mi codigo, cree un objeto con la propiedad nombre y un metodo (MostrarNombre) donde mando llamar el nombre para imprimirlo, pero no me muestra el resultado en la ejecucion, a continuacion muestro el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Luis, la pregunta/respuesta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, te sugiero que la edites, y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, para que no sea cerrada, y evitar recibir votos negativos, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y obtener una medalla!.

Comment: gracias Marce reformule mi pregunta, ¿estoy siendo redundante al plantearla? ¿es poco util la pregunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu idea no es equivocada, mas no tu sintaxis, quizás buscabas hacer algo así:

```
const persona = {
  nombre: 'jorge',
  apellido: 'balsamo',
  saludar: function () {
    console.log(this.nombre)
  }
}

persona.saludar()
```

Comment: Problema resuelto, muchas gracias